# How to grant permission scope to an Azure App in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am updating a Powershell script to replace use of Azure CLI calls with PowerShell commands. The Powershell script creates a number of App Registrations in an Azure tenant, adds permissions to them, and then grants access to those permissions.

I am finding it difficult to replace the CLI calls granting access. Typically these calls grant a service principal access with a scope or scopes, e.g.

`az ad app permission grant --id $app.appId --api 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --scope "offline_access openid"`

I see no way to do this with the Cmdlets in the Azure Resources Module, and have not been to find a direct equivalent in the Azure Graph API. The nearest thing I have found in the Graph API is an endpoint for granting an App Role Assignment (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell) but that addresses a different problem, assigning roles rather than scopes.

I'm pretty new to Azure development, but I've been knocking my head off this one for a few days now, so any advice would be appreciated!

*Edit: Adding an example of a permission I'd like to be able to grant where Admin Consent is not required.*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine. Below statements are based on our analysis.

You can use the below PowerShell cmdlet to add a permission to the app registration.

```
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId "<objectID>" -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "<PermissionId>" -Type "<role(ApplicationPermissions),Scope(DelagatedPermissions)"
```

***Here is the sample Output screenshot for reference:***

[image]

As per the [Current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-7.1.0#description), **User needs to grant consent via Azure Portal** if the permission requires admin consent because **Azure PowerShell doesn't support it yet**.

**Note :**

Application permissions under the  `appRoles`  property correspond to  `Role`  in  `-Type`. Delegated permissions under the  `oauth2Permissions`  property correspond to  `Scope`  in  `-Type`.

Comment: That clarifies the Roles vs scopes issue, thanks, but I still need to grant consent. I accept that I can't do that for permissions that require admin consent, but how can I do it for other permissions?

Comment: @user871967 , could give us with some insights what is meant by other permissions.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a screenshot example. In the example I have two User.Read delegated permissions where Admin Consent is not required. Can I grant permission to them?

Comment: We have gone through your above-updated questions, for a couple of permission, you don't require admin consent like User.Read . So you can directly grant those permissions to the app registration.